# Android Galaxy Nexus: can't see folder when connecting as Media Device (MTP)

Tags: android, galaxy-nexus

An app I am debugging on an Android Galaxy Nexus creates a folder whose contents I want to inspect on my desktop. When I open a file browser app on the device, I can see the folder. However, when I connect to it from the desktop in the MTP mode, I can't see it. Nor can I see a copy of that folder that I create on the device using the file browser.

What can I do to make it visible from the desktop so that I could copy it over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a folder you created from code, you need to use `MediaConnection.scanFile()` to get it to show up in MTP. I have [a blog post from last year](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html) that explains a bit more.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. if I create a folder with a bunch of files in it, is it enough to scan only the folder or do I need to scan every file to make it visible?

Comment: @IZ: Good question. I have not tried creating a folder of files that needed to be indexed. I would hope that calling `scanFile()` on the folder would suffice, but I have not tried it myself. Sorry!

Comment: I just tried it. When I pass a folder path to scanFile, it seems to handle it as a file. That is, after I switch to MTP, I can navigate to the folder but it looks like a file and there is nothing underneath. Maybe I have explicitly recurse over files and subfolders and apply scanFile to each of them -- need to try that

Comment: +1 Thank you, solved a big newbie problem I was having, not seeing files I'd copied accross via the network